Unexpected error while translating a model
I recently went testing the library VirtualFCS under Dymola (it is on GitHub). After some QA on the code, I checked the example VirtualFCS.Examples.VehicleExamples.RangeExtenderHybridVehicle OK, and then running it leads to Translation error in the model that I cannot understand nor find the location, except it seems to be in the FuelCellSystem component. The message is:
The function emptySlot should only be found in left hand side of multiple output, but found:


There is no function emptySlot that I can find in the library nor in the MSL (just in case)
The message seems to remain incomplete as it does not show what has been found
No line number or component/function name where this is happening is provided

The model runs Ok under OpenModelica.
Has anyone already experienced such an error? Do you know what kind of error I'm to look for in the code?

This is not the only issue reported by Dymola. I get 65 errors and 83 warnings when I translate this model in Dymola 2025x. I think there is also room for improvement in the library. Maybe the reported issue is fixed when the other ones are solved.

I agree that this library needs improvement. I cleaned all other errors and warnings, on Dymola 2025x ref1. The reported issues are the only ones that remain during model translation.

This occurs for the Jacobian in a non-linear system where the residual involves a function with a partial function application, i.e., a function with a function as input (in this case the function is a non-linear function solver, there might be a better way of handling this as the model effectively inverts an inverse).
If you open a support request you should soon get access to a fix pack for it.
(Previously a comment on a now deleted answer.)
